# How to simulate water/ pool for underwater vehicle in Gazebo/SimScape?

Tags: mobile-robot, simulation, gazebo, underwater

I have tried SimScape and gazebo but I did not get a solution for simulation of a swimming pool. Can somebody help with the same? Do I have to create the whole swimming pool using simple rectangular shapes and all? How to add water to it?

Comment: Did you try to search for an answer?  http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=hydrodynamics&cat=plugins

Comment: Comments are for helping to improve questions and answers, and are distracting @LongSmith , so we try to keep them to a minimum. Partial answers, or answers you aren't confident about should still be posted as answers, since they can be improved by future edits. Comments should be considered ephemeral, any comment which no longer actively helps to improve a question or answer may be deleted at any time to *tidy up* a post. Also, please try to *[be nice](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)*, for guidelines, see our [Code of Conduct](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Answer (score 1):

Check UUV Simulator and UWSIM.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Vipul Garg. Thanks for your answer but we are looking for comprehensive answers that provide some explanation and context. Very short answers cannot do this, so please edit your answer to explain why it is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed or attracy "not useful" votes.